# Adding numbers on label when if-statement occurs

Tags: c#, if-statement, numbers, label, addition

I am making an app on windows forms application and I am stuck at a certain point.

btw, I am a very beginner in programming.

I put my code here:

```
        if (random.Next(3) == schat)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Schat, ClientRectangle);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Hoera je hebt extra geld gevonden", "zoektocht");
            lblTotaalGeld.Text = Convert.ToString(100);
            double totaalGeld = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotaalGeld.Text) / 100;
            lblTotaalGeld.Text = Convert.ToString("€" + lblTotaalGeld.Text);



            btnZoektocht.Enabled = false;
        }
```

What I am trying to create is when this "if" statements occurs the second time.. I want the extra 100 dollars added to the bank account. At the moment I only get 100 and nothing adds.

I hope I make sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: A)if the 100 is static , why are you converting it string than to double ?
B) what is the logic for "when this "if" statements occurs the second time" -> it seems like nothing here doing it

Comment: I see what you mean. Before this I tried:

int money = 100;
int TotalMoney = Convert.ToInt32(lblTotalMOney.text);
TotalMoney = TotalMoney + money;
lblTotaleMoney.Text = totalMoney.ToString();

If I do this then I get an error about the second line. That it cannot convert of some DateTime and I should parse it. But I don't understand what they mean :( my "programming" english isn't that good. I just want 100 and adding 100 when event occurs on bank account

Comment: Do you want 100 gold added to your label every time or only the second time. If you only want 100 gold added a second time, what do you want happen the first time or the times after that?

Comment: I don't know if there is a big difference. For me it's cool enough if I can add the 100 gold everytime this if-statement occurs.

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about this a few different ways but I will suggest this way.

**Store the value of what is inside your label in a `variable`/`property` outside the scope of your `method` and `if-statement` (global variable)**

For an example of a `Variable`, you can have something like

```
private double totalGold = 0.0;
```

Or for a `Property` you can have something similar to this

```
public double totalGold { get; private set; }
```

**Note:** Since you say that you are a beginner, the first of these examples might be better for grasping the concept.

**Also Note:** You will need to add `static` between (`private`/`public`) and your `variable`/`property` name if you are doing this in a `static class` or your `main class`.

The implementation of both ways is the same. All we do is update this `totalGold` value whenever we enter this `if-statement`.

A rework of your current `if-statement` might look like:

```
    if (random.Next(3) == schat)
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Schat, ClientRectangle);
        }

        totalGold += 100.0; // NEW LINE

        MessageBox.Show("Hoera je hebt extra geld gevonden", "zoektocht");
        lblTotaalGeld.Text = Convert.ToString("€" + totalGold);

        btnZoektocht.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I did needed to set this variable outside the method. If I am right.. and if I did place it in the method. The value would reset to 0 every time. I think :)

Thanks for reply

Comment: You are correct in saying that the value will reset if you have a variable declared inside the scope of the `if-statement`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double totaalGeld = 0;
```

Depending on how this if statement is occuring, you can put this variable at the begining of the code or as a global variable

```
if (random.Next(3) == schat)
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Schat, ClientRectangle);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Hoera je hebt extra geld gevonden", "zoektocht");
            totaalGeld += 100.0;
            lblTotaalGeld.text = totalGold.ToString();
         }
```

Now everytime this `if` statement occurs, `totaalGeld` will increment by 100 and the label `lblTotaalGeld` display the corresponding number

Hope this helps and will guide you to your solution !!

Comment: Thanks for reply. It did work! I needed to put the variable totalGold outside the method :)